# VueJs what is the difference between v-on:event and this.$on(event, handler)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-events

I'm learning about `Vuejs event handling`.
I think that the developer could use [`this.$on('event', handler)`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Programmatic-Event-Listeners) in `js` file to process the `'event'`.

There is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/p98uwfz4/8/).

```
<div id="mainapp" v-on:event="processEventFromView">
    <button type="button" v-on:click="emitEvent">
       Emit Event
    </button>
</div>
```

**js File**

```
var app = new Vue({
  el:"#mainapp",
  data:{
    show:false
  },
  created:function(){
     this.$on('event', this.processEvent);
  },
  methods:{
      emitEvent:function(){
          this.$emit('event', {data:'mydata'});
      },
      processEvent(data){
         console.log('js', data);  //this is fired when clicking the button.
      },
      processEventFromView(data){
         console.log('view', data);  //this is not fired whenever.
      }      

   }
})
```

But in the example, only the handler,`processEvent`, attached by `this.$on()` is fired when clicking the button.
What is the difference between `v-on` vs `this.$on`?
Why is  `v-on:event="processEventFromView"` not called whenever?
Could I attach the `event handler` to the `click` event of the button with reference, [`ref`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-refs),  instead of `v-on:click="emitEvent"`?
Please help me what I'm wrong.

Comment: I think (can't prove it yet) that Vue event emitting only traverses the component hierarchy and not the DOM.

Comment: For some perspective you can refer to [this issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vuejs.org/issues/1802).

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's related and answered by Linus Berg of Vue here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36159698/1225266
Although it's related to an earlier version of Vue (the post is from 2016) I guess it still applies.

In short the answer to your question

> Why is v-on:event="processEventFromView" not called whenever?

is (I quote)

> cannnot use v-on:custom-event-name in the template (that's only to be used on components).

Comment: @tony19 Have you tried w a _custom_ event where you emit the event with this.$emit like in OP, then it doesn't work. (@click is a 'standard dom event').

Comment: @tony19 still you're using v-on:custom in the component tag (which should work as stated by Linus Berg), and not in the template of the component which emits the event.